# How To Merge Deleted Revisions Into Trunk Using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, history, ankhsvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN. A fellow developer recently deleted several of my revisions from our trunk branch and I need to know how to restore them. If I view the history on trunk, the revisions are not there. If I view the history on the entire repository, I can see my revisions. How do I get these revisions back into trunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to augment the previous answer:

1. Go into Repo Browser by right clicking on any file in the explorer
2. click on the head button (top right)
3. enter the revision that your colleague "deleted"

You should then see the missing stuff and be able to check it out and remerge if necessary in the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no deleting revisions in SVN. You can only revert revisions and that creates new commit(s). So I find it weird that you don't find your revisions in Trunk. So if you are seeing them when you are viewing the log of the entire repo, that means the revisions were never in trunk, but only in some other branch.

If you had mistaken the "not seeing the revisions on trunk" part and the revisions are there, you can revert the commit which reverted yours. If they are only in some other branch and reverted in that branch, you can still choose the revisions ( that were later reverted ) and merge into trunk.